# How to edit the length of margins

Tags: margins

I want to decrease the length of margins, which are denoted on the picture (because i fint them too long). How can i do that?

[image: a picture with margins]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx, graphics}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\title{ticket9}
\author{myname}

\section{introduction}
\vskip 0.1 cm
Some text

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,heightrounded]{geometry}`. For details `texdoc geometry` from terminal.